# Woocommerce password Reset

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, password, reset

The website generates an pre-worded email to the customer if they go in and change their password. The issue is that this email currently mentions an incorrect site administrator with a link.  How to change that "sender " email

Answer (score 1):

That uses the site admin email address. Changing that will change the email address that is sent.

[image]

Comment: In woocommerce also, is that the same?

Comment: The password change email pulls the site Admin Email Address by default. If you update that, it will change the emails that get sent out.

Comment: Thank you Mark! Have a great day ahead

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer correct if it works for you!